# Does Sitecore Azure paas support sticky session?

Tags: azure, paas

I want to enable Sticky session on Azure Pass Sitecore CD instances(multiple app services). Is this possible? If not, what are other options that I have?

Comment: Take a look on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114845/azure-web-app-and-sticky-session-with-affinity-cookie-reliable

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible, however, since you didn't specify if you are running a Scaled Out or multiple App Services for the CD instance, I am going to cover your options for that.

1. **Scaled Out**

When you Scale Out, [a Load Balancer will handle the traffic when a visitor access your website, and distribute the traffic to one of the instances of your Azure App Service](https://viniciusdeschamps.com.br/azure-web-app-scale-out-and-arr-affinity/). In order to avoid that your users jumps from instance to instance, you can use ARR Affinity which is enabled by default in Azure App Service.

[image]

2. **Multiple App Services**

Using this approach, you won't have the benefit in have a Load Balancer automatically added in front of your CDs, so you will need to either add an Azure Application Gateway or
use a third party solution for that.
The Azure Application Gateway has the option to enable Cookie Based Affinity, just make sure it is enabled and you should be fine

[image]

[image]